# Error in fetching text sms details?

Tags: android, android-layout, sms, smsmanager

I'm creating this post to get help. I am developing an application which sends `incoming text sms`.What I'm doing is fetching `incoming message body, date and time` and send it as new message. for sending purpose I'm using `sms manager`. 
I'm able to get `multiple message body` using `checkboxes` and creating a `list` of selected messages. But the problem is in getting their date and time.

Code in main Activity:

```
String body="";
ArrayAdapter<SMSListModel> adapter;
List<SMSListModel> list = new ArrayList<SMSListModel>();
```

Code for array list of selected messages:

```
 private List<SMSListModel> getModel() 
{
    if(cursor.getCount()>0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
        {
            if(cursor.moveToPosition(i))
            {
                list.add(new SMSListModel(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")),cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"))));
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Code for SMSListModel

```
  public SMSListModel(String address, String body) {
    this.address = address;
    this.body = body;
}
public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}
```

Code to send selected message body:

```
if(list.size()>0){
       for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
       {
           if(list.get(i).isSelected())
           {
            if(body.equals(""))
                   body =list.get(i).getBody();

               else
                body =list.get(i).getBody();
             try
             {
                 String mbody = "from"+ "dd/mm/yy" +"hh:mm"+body;
                 SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                 smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, mbody, null, null);
             }                           
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                 //Error Occurred if No Messages Selected 
                    e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

Comment: your code snippet seems to be incomplete

Comment: @donfuxx yes it need to have code regarding date and time for that I need help

Comment: @joaquin apart from editing can you help me with the problem for which  I'm asking

Comment: No, apart from editing, otherwise I would have done.

Answer (score 1):

few code Still zmissing friend but well we can fix code which you post and give you direction for existing one and which you did't post here..

First modify Code for SMSListModel

```
public class SMSListModel {

    String date;
    String time;
    String address;
    String body;

    public SMSListModel(String address, String body, String time, String date) {
        this.address = address;
        this.body = body;
        this.time = time;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
    public boolean isSelected() {
           return selected;
    }
    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
    }

}
```

Change update Code for array list of selected messages:

```
private List<SMSListModel> getModel() 
{
    if(cursor.getCount()>0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
        {
            if(cursor.moveToPosition(i))
            {
                list.add(new SMSListModel(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")),cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"))),cursor.getColumnIndex("time")) , cursor.getColumnIndex("date")) );
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

**NOTE : For cursor.getColumnIndex("time")) and  cursor.getColumnIndex("date")) first you need to create two column with name time,date in your database class and also insert value for that when sms receive.**

Code to send selected message body

```
if(list.size()>0){
       for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
       {
           if(list.get(i).isSelected())
           {
            if(body.equals(""))
                   body =list.get(i).getBody();
                   date =list.get(i).getDate();
                   time =list.get(i).getTime();

               else
                body =list.get(i).getBody();
                date =list.get(i).getDate();
                time =list.get(i).getTime();
             try
             {
                 String mbody = "from"+ date + time +body;
                 SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                 smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, mbody, null, null);
             }                           
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                 //Error Occurred if No Messages Selected 
                    e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

**Note: You need to modify your database. for that modify table and add two column at end "time" and "date".

after that you also need to change your broadcastReceiver subclass's code which receive message and store this message into database. from that class you also need to enter time and date value to your table.**

Comment: but how can I use this for multiple messages selected

Comment: can you please post your code here.? and as you deal with sms body and maintain list of that also maintain date and time. i can not give you perfect code because you didnt post whole code. so please if you can then post it

Comment: check my edits through which I'm maintaining selected messages list through which after selection i'm fetching msg body to be send

Comment: i post your code back with some modification just check it and also modify other code which i mention as note . and try to understand your code you need to post whole code . incomplete code hard to understand for both you and me.